# Jenkins allow comma separated values to be passed one by one to generate job dsl

Tags: jenkins, dsl, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a seed job which takes in a parameter say project and invokes a "Process Job DSL" to create the generated jobs.
However, I need to do the same for multiple projects.
Wondering, if there is a way in Jenkins for me to provide the list and it iterates through each of those choices and create its job.
I looked into Extended Choice Parameter but that too passes all the parameters at once.

I am interested in a way that it iterates through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote a python client that wraps [python-jenkins](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to do just this.  The caller supplies the dsl file and the url to the jenkins server.  The python client then calls the seed job, passing the dsl file as the argument.  The seed job is just:

```
node {
    stage('create-job') {
        jobDsl failOnMissingPlugin: true, scriptText: params.jobDsl
    }
}
```

To turn it into a loop, you would just iterate over the list of projects and invoke the client for each project.